# Downloads are not complete while creating write stream

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I have function with a callback to make sure the image download is finished.

If I have multiple images to be downloaded(around 11), It downloads all but the file size is not correct. Therefore some are corrupted.

I thought using the callback will make sure the downloads are done completely before moving on.

This is the code below I am using:

```
    imageExtractor(imageId,function(){
    zipmaker(imageId, function () {

       });
    });

 imageIndex =0;
 function imageExtractor(imageId, callback) {
  images.ImageIds.foreach(function (image){
   imageIndex++;


  // Here I call the download image function

 downloadImageFromURLAndSave(imageURL, imageId, category,callback) {
  if(images.length=seriesIndex){
  callback();
     }
 } 

}

function downloadImageFromURLAndSave(imageURL, imageId, category,callback) {
console.log("Download has started.");
console.log(imageURL);
request
    .get(imageURL)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + category+
     '/digital/' + imageId)
        .on('finish', function() {
        console.log("Download has finished for " + imageId+ " Congratulations.");
        callback();
    }));

}
```

It seems the function after this(zipmaker) is called early before the images are downloaded even though I have a callback as you can see.

Comment: Could we also have the functions after this/the whole script? that would be super helpful! thanks!

Comment: right now when I try to run the script request is undefined

Comment: Hi @ZoeCarver. Thanks for the reply. I basically call this function as I receive url from a json file. If I have 3 images, it downloads and the file sizes are correct.
The function after this is called early somehow if I have more images

Comment: ok, cool. It would still be great if you could at least add the part where you receive the url from the json file. Thanks

Comment: I just don't see what request is. and I am getting an error that request is undefined.

Comment: OK. I think I found the problem. I keep calling this function in a loop and when the first callback is successful, next function is called. I need the callback to be triggered when the loop is done.

Comment: ok glad I could act as a rubber ducky.

Comment: If you're doing a parallel op, use something like `async` to handle multiple simultaneous requests.

Comment: @ZoeCarver `request`: https://npmjs.org/package/request

Comment: Yeah, but didn't he use `imageURL` for that?

Comment: I just updated the code. Hope it makes more sense what I am trying to achieve. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I where you, here is how I would structure your code:

#### index.js:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');
var config = require('./test.json');
var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

for (var key in config) {
  if (config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    download(key, config[key], function(){
      console.log('done');
    });
  }
}
```

#### test.json:

```
{
  "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png": "google.png",
  "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg": "panda.jpg"
}
```

Hope this helps!